# How to add uncertain number of string arguments in a UDF using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to pass a string or several strings to a function by using `dplyr` but somehow it only takes the first variable in the argument but ignore others

```
library(lazyeval)
plotGenerationFct = function(data,..., targetVariable){   
  result = data %>% select_(..., targetVariable) %>% group_by_(...) %>% summarise_(mean= interp(~mean(var, na.rm = TRUE), var = as.name(targetVariable)))
  return(result)
}
```

And the expressions below give me the same result

```
plotGenerationFct(diamonds, c("cut"), targetVariable = "price")
plotGenerationFct(diamonds, c("cut","color"), targetVariable = "price")
plotGenerationFct(diamonds, c("cut","color","clarity"), targetVariable = "price")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard evaluation version of the `dplyr` functions are net set up to accept vectors as standard parameters. For that use the `.dots=` parameter

```
plotGenerationFct = function(data, vars, targetVariable){   
  result = data %>% select_(.dots=c(vars, targetVariable)) %>% 
      group_by_(.dots=vars) %>%  
      summarise_(mean= interp(~mean(var, na.rm = TRUE), var = as.name(targetVariable)))
  return(result)
}
```

So these are all the same

```
select(diamonds, cut, color)
select_(diamonds, "cut", "color")
select_(diamonds, .dots=c("cut", "color"))
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!